# How to get upload percentage (as an integer) of the primefaces component fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `p:fileupload` but I don't want to use its own progressbar. I want to create a label with the upload percentage as value near the upload button. Problem is I can't get any information of the upload status from client side (javascript). Is there any way (method, variable..) to get this status ? thanks

Comment: What is the advatange of using ace ? How can I get upload status from ace component ?

Comment: Thanks Ravi, but this has nothing to do with my question. I want to get the value of upload progress in client side when the file is uploaded.

Comment: so you should use jquery file upload .. :)

Comment: @SamiDjo, you may want to experiment with `<p:progressBar/>`. It provides a status counter variable that can read. The challenge would be hiding the progress bar so it doesn't duplicate the bar already provided with the `<p:fileUpload/>`

Comment: @kolossus : the `<p:progressBar>` doesn't give any information about the upload status. It's only when you have that information that you can bind it with a `<p:progressBar>`.